# How to add tolerances/gaps in OnShape?

Tags: 3d-design, cad, print-preparation

When printing parts that fit together, there's a need to offset them from each other with a slight gap to provide for the printer tolerances. It's possible to take that into account from the very beginning when designing parts, but it makes the initial design far more complicated. Is it possible to effectively "offset" all faces of a part, the same way you' offset lines of a sketch?

Essentially, asking the same question as this, but for OnShape:

[How to add tolerances/gaps in 123d Design?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/2970/how-to-add-tolerances-gaps-in-123d-design)

Answer (score 2):

OnShape has a "Move Face" tool that can do exactly this: select the relevant faces to move, and then choose "offset" as the "Move Type". You can do all your offsets at once, but because I'm often selecting a lot of faces, I find it easiest to create one offset per part, and hide the other parts to be able to drag to select groups of faces at once. (and then I use a variable to hold the amount by which to offset). I find this makes it easier to fix the offsets when making changes to the parts earlier in the part history.

[image: OnShape offset face dialog]